# How to include NLTK in a python project

Tags: python

I tried downloading the latest NLTK release, and moving the nltk directory included in the zip file to my python project's working directory. Then I tried calling import nltk. Usually, to the best of my understanding, this would work - but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akf/PycharmProjects/comrad/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    import plugins.nltk               as plugins_nltk
  File "/home/akf/PycharmProjects/comrad/plugins/nltk/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import config_java
ImportError: No module named nltk.internals
```

It's accurate, I can't find this file either. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some libs, simply downloading the folder isn't going to work. You need more than just downloading it to actually install it, and before installing it make sure you have dependencies like `numpy` first.

Also managing dependencies with something like `pip` is better, you can track versions, upgrade etc, without having to manually removing and re-downloading the folder.

Seems you're working on Linux or UNIX? Here is a guide on how to install it http://www.nltk.org/install.html